# Specifically, how/can I use the dotnet cert generated certificate in my android emulator running MAUI to accept the certificate as a CA

Tags: ssl, openssl, android-emulator, ssl-certificate, maui

I'm going around in circles a bit on a problem using the dotnet generated self-signed HTTPS certificate in my Android Emulator when trying to test my MAUI project on a Windows 11 Machine.

I've read quite a few posts now on how the new Android OS versions are more secure, and I've read countless articles that talk about accepting a big scary warning on installing a certificate but I haven't read any yet that actually work for me.

So far, the things I've tried are to use the tool

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Which creates a self signed certificate as usual and assigns it to my local user Personal Certificate store. That's fine. At this point I then tried to add it to my android emulator by dropping this file into the file explorers SD / Documents folder and using the Settings -> Security -> More security settings -> Encryption & credentials -> Install a certificate -> CA certificate [choosing Install Anyway] and then trying to choose my 'ca-cert.crt' file which I also had to extract from the PFX file from windows. This immediately failed as it wasn't a CA authority certificate (I assume).

- And as a first question is it actually a CRT file that the Android System wants in the first place?

In order to actually provide a CRT file I needed to extract the CRT from the PFX so I've used OpenSSL on windows using the commands that I found in this helpful article https://medium.com/beingcoders/easy-way-to-convert-pfx-to-crt-key-files-in-10-minutes-683849242c65 which boiled down to this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfilename.pfx] -nocerts -out [keyfilename-encrypted.key]
openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfilename.pfx] -clcerts -nokeys -out [certificatename.crt]
```

Which gave me a CRT file which I then tried to put into the Android Emulator. Upon selecting the CRT file in the emulator, I get no warning, no error, no toast just nothing. Upon inspection I established that the crt also didn't seem to be a CA authority so this is my first best guess at the problem.

Next thing I tried was copying the Personal Certificate into my machines Trusted Root Certificate Authority. Do I then need to re-export this and do something with it? Will that now be a CA?

I am not a security / certificate expert so please use short words so I'll be sure to understand you if you can help me!